# Generate a "random" color set

Tags: code-golf

Your challenge is to write a program that takes input from *stdin*, creates a set of `1` to `n`colors and outputs them on *stdout*, formatted as a 6-digit-hex value with a prefixed #.

- The starting color should have following values (in a hsv colorspace) (pesudocode)

  - `h=rand(), s=0.5, v=0.95`.
- Every subsequent color should have its *hue* value increased by

  - `1/Φ`
- After every 5th color, the *saturation* and *value* for the forthcoming colors should be

  - *saturation* - increased by `0.1`
  - *value* - decreased by `0.2`

*e.g.*

```
Color  #    h         s       v  
       1  0.5        0.5     0.95
       2  0.118...   0.5     0.95
      11  0.680...   0.7     0.55
```

**Input**

Your program shall receive an Integer `n`as input *(stdin)*, which defines the number of colors, to be generated. *Where `0 < n < 16`*

**Output**

- On each call, the *hues*' start value  should be different from the last call *(Don't just take the same random start number on every call)*
- Output should be on stdout with one color per line.
- The array shall contain `n` different hex codes.
- The hex codes should be prefixed with a "#" and be padded with a "0", such that you always get a 7 character string like "#FFFFFF"

**Additional Rules**

- The use of built in functions/tools/etc  for the following conversions is forbidden

  - HSV->RGB
  - RGB->HEX representation of RGB<sub>a function which specifically converts rgb to hex, generic tools like `sprintf` are ok.</sub>
  - HSV->HEX representation of RGB<sub>just to make sure...</sub>

**Scoring**

The size of your code in bytes.

**Test Cases**<sub>(result of rand() in parantheses)</sub>

```
3 (0.35389856481924653) -> 
    #79f388
    #f3798e
    #79b1f3
    
8 (0.763850917108357) -> 
    #c079f3
    #79f39d
    #f37979
    #4c6ec0
    #90c04c
    #c04cb1
    #4cc0ac
    #c08b4c
    
15 (0.10794945224188268) -> 
    #f3c879
    #a479f3
    #79f381
    #f37995
    #79b8f3
    #aac04c
    #b44cc0
    #4cc092
    #c0704c
    #4f4cc0
    #448c2a
    #8c2a61
    #2a7e8c
    #8c7e2a
    #612a8c
```

*for a visualization of the codes, you can paste your output [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SCnd6/)*

*I will change the accepted Answer, as soon as new appear*

Comment: Could you include the value received from `rand()` in the test cases to make testing easier?

Comment: Can you define "rgb->hex tool"? Does `sprintf("%2x"*3,r,g,b)` count?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think `sprintf` is definetly eligible

Comment: @flornquake Yupp, i'll update the question

Comment: Please clarify what `1/Φ` means.

Comment: @DavidCarraher _Φ_ is the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), approximately _1.618_. Hue is defined on _[0, 1]_, the value one being exactly once around the unit circle. _1/Φ_ (or equivalently _Φ-1_) is approximately _3.883_ radians, or _222.5_ degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 184 bytes

```
from random import*
h,s,v=random()*6,.5,243.2
for i in range(input()):
 h+=3.708;print'#'+'%02x'*3%((v,v-v*s*abs(1-h%2),v-v*s)*3)[5**int(h)/3%3::int(h)%2+1][:3]
 if i%5/4:s+=.1;v-=51.2
```

The HSV ⇒ RGB conversion is taken directly from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV).

A few implementation notes.

- `h` is defined as its proper value times *6*, which simplifies region determination.
- `v` is defined as its proper value times *256*, which propagates through to all three RGB values.
- *6/Φ*  (approximately *~3.708*) is used instead of *1/Φ*, in agreement with the scaling of `h`. Similarly, the decrement value for `v` is also scaled by *256*.
- The bit of magic
  `((v,v-v*s*abs(1-h%2),v-v*s)*3)[5**int(h)/3%3::int(h)%2+1][:3]`
  is logically equivalent to
  `c=v*s;m=v-c;x=c-c*abs(1-h%2)+m;c+=m;[(c,x,m),(x,c,m),(m,c,x),(m,x,c),(x,m,c),(c,m,x)][int(h)%6]`

Sample usage:

```
$ echo 3 | python color-set.py
#f37994
#79b8f3
#dbf379

$ echo 8 | python color-set.py
#d2f379
#f079f3
#79f3cc
#f3a979
#8579f3
#62c04c
#c04c84
#4ca6c0

$ echo 15 | python color-set.py
#7984f3
#a8f379
#f379cb
#79eff3
#f3d379
#804cc0
#4cc05e
#c04c5c
#4c7dc0
#9fc04c
#8b2a8c
#2a8c6f
#8c522a
#352a8c
#3b8c2a
```

A visualization of the values for *n = 15*:
[image]
and the [corresponding html](http://codepad.org/9IJy6Jt4).

Comment: Nice solution! And Thanks for the update about the HSV to RGB conversion and the visualization =)

Answer (score 3):

As I saw by other People, i start with my own solution

## Javascript, <del>418</del>433

```
a=prompt();x=0.6180339887;r=[];m=Math.random;p=[m(),0.5,0.95];function h(c,g,d){k=~~(6*c);b=6*c-k;c=d*(1-g);l=d*(1-b*g);g=d*(1-(1-b)*g);f=e=b=255;1>k?(b=d,e=g,f=c):2>k?(b=l,e=d,f=c):3>k?(b=c,e=d,f=g):4>k?(b=c,e=l,f=d):5>k?(b=g,e=c,f=d):(b=d,e=c,f=l);return"#"+[b,e,f].map(function(c){return 16>(c=0|256*c)?0:""+c.toString(16)}).join("")}for(;a--;)r.push(h.apply(h,p)),p[0]+=x,p[0]%=1,!(a%5)&&(p[1]+=0.1,p[2]-=0.2);console.log(r.join("\n"))
```

*Damn, i did something wrong in the previous versioon when inlining the function, i shouldn't write the code golfed from beginning*

Sample Output

[image]

```
#79f3a0
#f37d79
#7999f3
#bcf379
#f379e0
#4cc0b0
#c08e4c
#6d4cc0
#4ec04c
#c04c6f
#2a648c
#818c2a
#7b2a8c
#2a8c5e
#8c412a
```